# Searching for file in folder and placing it in another folder

Tags: string, sorting, search, applescript

Two days ago I learned a little about applescripting - it's my first time "programming" so you'll probably see some funny stuff:

```
    tell application "Finder"
--I don't really know why I use as string but otherwise it won't work
set strFilepath to selection as string
set mainFolder to strFilepath
if (exists strFilepath & "ro") is false then
    make new folder at mainFolder with properties {name:"ro"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "ro" with properties {name:"carta"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "ro" with properties {name:"A4"}
end if
if (exists strFilepath & "ingl") is false then
    make new folder at mainFolder with properties {name:"ingl"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "ingl" with properties {name:"carta"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "ingl" with properties {name:"A4"}
end if
if (exists strFilepath & "es") is false then
    make new folder at mainFolder with properties {name:"es"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "es" with properties {name:"carta"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "es" with properties {name:"A4"}
end if
if (exists strFilepath & "it") is false then
    make new folder at mainFolder with properties {name:"it"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "it" with properties {name:"carta"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "it" with properties {name:"A4"}
end if
if (exists strFilepath & "fr") is false then
    make new folder at mainFolder with properties {name:"fr"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "fr" with properties {name:"carta"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "fr" with properties {name:"A4"}
end if
if (exists strFilepath & "port") is false then
    make new folder at mainFolder with properties {name:"port"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "port" with properties {name:"carta"}
    make new folder at mainFolder & "port" with properties {name:"A4"}
end if
--it does what I want up until here
set allFiles to entire contents of mainFolder
--here I get an error nummber -1728, I guess because of that string... 
try
    --I guess this code also doesn't work… I have PDF files that end like xxx_it_carta.pdf, xxx_it_A4.pdf, xxx_en_carta.pdf, etc
    search of (name of every item of allFiles) for "_it_carta"
    if file exists then move to mainFolder & "it" & "carta"
end try
search of (name of every item of allFiles) for "_it_A4"
try
    if file exists then move to mainFolder & "it" & "A4"
end try
--and so on
    end tell
```

Please help me arrange this code so I'll have this working and I'll understand a little bit more about applescript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
    set folderNameList to {"ro", "ingl", "es", "it", "fr", "port"}

tell application "Finder"
    set strFilepath to (get selection) as text
    repeat with folderName in folderNameList
        if not (exists folder (strFilepath & folderName)) then make new folder at strFilepath with properties {name:folderName}
    end repeat

    set allFiles to entire contents of folder strFilepath
    -- not clear on your move command
    move (files of (entire contents of folder strFilepath) whose name ends with "_it_carta") to folder (strFilepath & "it")
end tell
```

EDIT

```
set folderNameList to {"ro", "ingl", "es", "it", "fr", "port"}

tell application "Finder"
    set strFilepath to (get selection) as text
    repeat with folderName in folderNameList
        set newFolder to POSIX path of (strFilepath & folderName) & "/" 
        do shell script "mkdir -p " & (quoted form of newFolder) & "{\"A4\",\"carta\"}"
    end repeat

    set allFiles to entire contents of folder strFilepath
    -- not clear on your move command
    move (files of (entire contents of folder strFilepath) whose name ends with "_it_carta") to folder (strFilepath & "it")
end tell
```

Comment: Cool! That looks a lot better (and shorter)... 
Thanks!

Any idea on the searching part?

Comment: The last line searches for files that end with "_it_carta" and moves them to the "it" folder

Comment: Great! It works... Could you adapt the code so that every folder in the list also has two subfolders {"A4", "carta"}. I tried it myself and only in the last folder (port) it worked - the rest stayed empty...

Thanks so much!